# How to combine Curry() with Vectorize()?

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization, currying

Consider the following function:

```
addAmount <- function(x, amount) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == 1)
  return(x + amount)
}
```

It can be used to add some `amount` to `x`:

```
> addAmount(x = 5, amount = 3)
[1] 8
> addAmount(x = 2, amount = 3)
[1] 5
```

However, `x` must be of length 1:

```
> addAmount(x = 7:9, amount = 3)
 Error: length(x) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I added this restriction intentionally for exemplification.

Using `Vectorize`, it is possible to pass in a vector for `x`:

```
> Vectorize(addAmount)(x = 7:9, amount = 3)
[1] 10 11 12
```

So far, so good.

However, I'd like to turn my `addAmount` function into a "add 3" function, using currying:

```
add3 <- functional::Curry(addAmount, amount = 3)
```

This works as expected if `x` is of length 1 and fails (as expected) if `x` is not of length 1:

```
> add3(x = 5)
[1] 8
> add3(x = 7:9)
 Error: length(x) == 1 is not TRUE
```

The problem is: `add3` cannot be vectorized:

```
> Vectorize(add3)(x = 7:9)
 Error: length(x) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Somehow, the curried function is not "compatible" with `Vectorize`, i.e. it behaves as if it had not been vectorized at all.

**Question:** What can I do about this? How can currying and vectorization be combined? (And: What is going wrong?)

---

I found a workaround (heavily inspired by [Hadley's `add` function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments)) using environments instead of `Curry`, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution that doesn't require this kind of clumsy "factory" functions:

```
getAdder <- function(amount) {
  force(amount)
  addAmount <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(length(x) == 1)
    return(x + amount)
  }
  return(addAmount)
}

add3 <- getAdder(3)
Vectorize(add3)(x = 7:9)
[1] 10 11 12
```

---

Tested with R 3.4.1 and the `functional` package (version 0.6).

Comment: What about vectorizing before currying: `add3 <- functional::Curry(Vectorize(addAmount), amount = 3)`

Comment: @eipi10 I was about to write the same comment :) To elaborate on the reason why the OP's approach did not work: the currification process in R is a bit weird. `functional::Curry(addAmount, amount = 3)` returns a function accepting only unamed arguments (`...`) that are processed in a custom environment. That's not something the `Vectorize` function can work with. On the other hand, currying the vectorized function returned by `Vectorize(addAmount)` is piece of cake.

Comment: A remark: if you reaallllyy wanted to vectorize the curried function, you could do it with a named wrapper for `x`: e.g. `add3 = Vectorize(function(x){functional::Curry(addAmount, amount = 3)(x=x)}); add3(x=7:9)`

Comment: Oh - I don't know why, but vectorizing before currying never came to my mind. I'd happily accept any answer along the lines of the three comments by eipi10 and Jealie. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize before currying:

```
add3 <- functional::Curry(Vectorize(addAmount), amount = 3)

add3(1:10)
```

> [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13