# Vectorizing a curried function in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble understanding how R works, and I'm starting to think it doesn't.

I am using a curried function `g` which I want to vectorize and obtain multiple values. My first attempt was to make `h1` which didn't work. However `h2` does work, but I fail to see why.

```
# Example function
f <- function(a, b) { return(prod(a, b)) }

# Curried function
g <- Curry(f, b=2)

# Vectorize functions
h1 <- Vectorize(g)
h2 <- Vectorize(function(x) return(g(x)))

# Result values
h1(c(1,2,3)) # returns unexpected result 12
h2(c(1,2,3)) # returns expected result c(2, 4, 6)
```

Why does wrapping `g` inside `function(x) return(g(x))` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine Curry() with Vectorize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038206/how-to-combine-curry-with-vectorize)

Comment: @avenger012 The question is similar, but I cannot reverse the Vectorization/Curry order in my situation, so the answer is not satisfactory. I am also more interested in "why", not "how".

Comment: Would `functional::Curry(Vectorize(f), b=2)` satisfy your need? In `h1` you are actually passing the function `g` as the argument to vectorize, `mapply(function(x) x, x = g(c(1,2,3))) = 12`. In `h2` you are passing `x` as the argument to vectorize, `mapply(function(x) g(x), x = c(1,2,3)) = c(2,4,6)`.